# how to integrate cwac-Camera into my application

Tags: android, commonsware-cwac

I have integrated cwac-camera lib , but getting error, even when I try to run camera-demo available with lib, getting error

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.commonsware.cwac.camera.CameraView.lockToLandscape(boolean)' on a null object reference

FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 Process: com.commonsware.cwac.camera.demo, PID: 22883
 java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.commonsware.cwac.camera.CameraView.lockToLandscape(boolean)' on a null object reference
    at com.commonsware.cwac.camera.CameraFragment.lockToLandscape(CameraFragment.java:197)
    at com.commonsware.cwac.camera.demo.MainActivity$1.run(MainActivity.java:120)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:738)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5070)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:836)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:631)
```

help will be appriciated.

I am testing with Nexus5 OS Android L,

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `lockToLandscape()` on `null` instead of on an instance of `CameraView`.

Comment: @Hitesh_Androiduser3797630: Please post your entire stack trace.

Comment: @Hitesh_Androiduser3797630: I have not tested this library on "L" and will not be doing so until August at the earliest. If you can reproduce the problem on a device that is running a production version of Android, [file an issue](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-camera/issues?state=open) with the stack trace and the device information.

Comment: I get .apk from zip and it's run fine in Android L, so I think OS is not problem for my Issue, it is work for getSupportFragment instead of getFragment

Comment: @Hitesh_Androiduser3797630: "I get .apk from zip" -- I do not know what APK and what ZIP you are referring to. "it is work for getSupportFragment instead of getFragment" -- both the regular and the `-v9` demo work, though I have not tried either of them on "L".